# Login into a website from a different website

Tags: c#, .net, forms, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two websites. Both websites have a login form.
From Website A I want to login to Website B.

From Website A in my form which posts to Website B. This works and can log me in! However, if anything goes wrong I get the login form on website B telling me the error.

```
<form action="http://websiteB.mycompany.com/login" method="post">
```

What I am trying to do now is

```
    <form action="login" method="post">

This now hits controller on WebSite A. I am then trying the following.

 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string username, string password)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://websiteB.mycompany.com/login");

            var postData = $"username={username}&password={password}";
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


            return View(); // Here I would redirect to website B or show an error message on website A
        }
```

The following code hits website B. The user authentication code runs without a problem but it doesn't seem that the session cookie is being sent back. Without this when you hit http://websiteB.mycompany.com you get directed to the login page.

The session cookie from website B has the following

[image: cookie]

On my test/production server, the cookie is secure.

Is there anything I can do to login to the site?

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible for you to set a cookie on a different domain. Learn about SSO techniques.

Comment: Both sites are running under mycompany.com. Each site is on a different subdomain

Comment: Then you can set the cookie on the parent domain in your own response.

Comment: "From Website A in my form which posts to Website B. This works and can log me in!" IMO this is a security flaw. The form should have some sort of CSRF protection, otherwise it could be abused. If both sites are under your control I would think about using some sort of federated identity provider instead.